# Material design not showing on new "Empty Acitivity" templated app

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, material-design, android-xml

I'm trying to learn Android development. I'm clicking the template for "Empty Activity," which shows a nice Material Toolbar with a back button. However, I don't see it when I view the main layout xml file. Am I doing something wrong? Is it supposed to be like this? The tutorial shows it differently than mine:

**Tutorial shows Material toolbar:**

[image]

**Mine shows nothing:**
[image]

Here's a video of me reproducing the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38iK2.jpg

Here is the activity_main.xml that Android Studio create for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Android studio changed those templates a while ago, probably the codelab, which you are trying to follow, is outdated.

Comment: I see the same templates as the ones in the tutorial, and installed a fresh Android Studio a few days ago.

Comment: Do you have a link to this codelab? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Yes it's here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-hello-world/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#3

Comment: From what i see, you have the exact same code, probably the rendering inside Android Studio changed inside the last half year, so they don't display it anymore. Just continue the codelab, when you will run in on a device, it will look just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to click `eye` icon/button and choose `"Show Layout Decorations"`

[image: Preview]